# Rename SQL table with [ ] in name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-rename

Through a stupid mistake I managed to rename a table to now contain [ and ] characters.
No matter what I try to feed sp_rename it keeps failing to identify the table.

How can I fix this?

Here is partial output from

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Casaba | dbo | **[dbo.Customer]** | BASE_TABLE |
| Casaba | dbo | Workspace | BASE_TABLE |

I tried

`sp_rename '[dbo.Customer]', 'Customer'` -> no item by the name of '[dbo.Customer]' could be found

`sp_rename 'dbo.[dbo.Customer]', 'Customer'` -> no item by the name of 'dbo.[dbo.Customer]' could be found

`sp_rename '\[dbo.Customer\]', 'Customer'` -> Syntac error parsing SQL itentifier '[dbo.Customer]'

many other variations all produce the same error.

Even if I can't rename the table, I would at least like to select all the data into another table, but SELECT has the same issue, and after that I'd probably also fail to delete that table.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Dale, that was not intuitive.